# Action Editor keyframes only showing when I have bone selected

Tags: keyframes, actions

In the action editor, my keyframes only show when I have the corresponding bone selected. Before, they were showing regardless if I had the bone selected or not. So how can I switch it back so the keyframes show at all times? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide the blend file or at least a screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Dopesheet you may have the *Only Show Selected* option (former *Only Include Channels Relating To Selected Objects*) enabled, just disable it.

[image]